# How to deal with multicollinearity in r

Tags: r, meta-analysis, multicollinearity

I am using `metafor` package for my meta-analysis. As part of the meta-analysis, I did a meta-regression analysis where I found out there is a multicollinearity issue across the variables I used. Is there any way to deal with it in `metafor` package?

I was suggested to use `bayesian model averaging (BMA)`. I am doing an ecological meta-analysis where my effect size is computed with `response ratio (treatment/control`, in such case, is it still possible to use `BMA`?

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the collinearity this is going to be hard to answer.